# Problema al clonar proyecto con git y netbeans por certificado ssl

Tags: git, ssl, netbeans-8.0

No puedo clonar un proyecto almacenado en un servidor de *Gitlab* en *AWS*, mediante *Netbeans*.

El servidor no tiene *certificado SSL*, razón por la que *Netbeans* no me deja conectar al repositorio.

¿Hay alguna configuración en *Netbeans* para que a la hora de clonar se salte dicha certificación?, ya que en el *git-config* de los proyectos se puede hacer dicha operación, pero como el clonado no tiene tal archivo me preguntaba si es posible hacer esto.

***Nota:*** no puedo adicionar el certificado al servidor, ya que hay alguien especializado para ésta tarea, pero necesito clonar urgentemente un proyecto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: es decir vas a clonar el proyecto de aws a un pc local ?

Comment: Exactamente Diego

Comment: y no puedes usar el famoso git clone 'url/miproyecto'